# How to detect the value of color picker in text input and show it in preview instantly?

Tags: jquery

I want to show a preview of plugin output with color changes instantly. For getting values from input text I will use the

- keyup
- changed
- on click

functions.

But in case of color picker user is interacting with the color picker so the above functions are not working, obviously it will work only if user focus or enter some input so I used the `setInterval` function

```
setInterval(function () {
    var h = jQuery('#bgcolor').val();
    jQuery(".bat-gh").css("background", h);
}, 100);
```

This is working perfectly fine I can show the output which the user is selecting.

Here is my question:

1. Will this create extra burden or load to my plugin or make the browser
   non-responsive?
2. Any other alternative way to show the color values when user
   changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add onChange event.

```
var myOptions = {
    // a callback to fire whenever the color changes to a valid color
   -----> change: function(event, ui){}, <-----------------------
    };

$('.my-color-field').wpColorPicker(myOptions);
```

Comment: i'm already having a color picker, Only thing is when user change the color i can't able to get the event by that i can use that value to show preview instantly

Comment: Are you having your own color picker ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one used the ui object directly. In my case, the change listener + a jQuery selector didn't get me an updated color value. For this, I had to do the following:

```
$('.my-color-field').wpColorPicker({
  change: function(event, ui){
    var theColor = ui.color.toString();
  } 
});
```

Comment: it's the best solution the problem, that is fired also when you move the selector on the picker so generate many request.

Answer (score 1):

No need to mess around with intervals when you can update the colour when the value is changed. And since it works with the setInterval, it has to work on change as well as the plugin will update this value when you click on a colour. So:

```
jQuery('#bgcolor').change(function(){
    jQuery(".bat-gh").css( "background", $(this).val() );
});
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* jQuery */
if( $('.stwpmodpop-cpicker').length ) {

    $('.stwpmodpop-cpicker').wpColorPicker({
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            var theColor = ui.color.toString();
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings('.stwpmodpop-fillcolor').html( theColor );
        }
    });
}

/* HTML */
<p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control stwpmodpop-cpicker" name="colorpicker_example" value="" />
    <span class="stwpmodpop-fillcolor"></span>
</p>
```